# Excel comparing data and returning non matched value

Tags: excel

I have a list of values in A.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

And I have a list of values in B.

```
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

So here, I want to match the values of B(unordered) to A(unordered) that are existent in both and return the unmatched values. So the returned values would be 10, 11. A would contain more values than B by nature.

What command should I run on excel to achieve this?

```
A       B      C
1       9      True
2       8      True
3       7      True
4       6      True
5       5      True
6       4      True
7       3      True
8       2      True
9       1      True
10             Error or 10
11             Error or 11
```

This is just an example. I want to achieve column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this formula in C1 and copy down

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=0,A1,TRUE)
```

Explanation: `COUNTIF(B:B,A1)` counts how often the value in cell A1 appears in column B. If the count returns a zero, i.e. if the value in A1 is NOT present in  column B, the outer IF statement will return the value of cell A1 (you could also return a text like "Error" or "Not found"). If the count returns a number greater than zero, that means the value has been found, so the IF statement returns TRUE.

The formula could also be written like this

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1),True,A1)
```

Explanation: Countif() will always return a numeric value. If something is found the value is greater than 0. If nothing is found, the value will be 0. In an Excel formula, the value 0 is equivalent to a Boolean "false" and any number greater than zero is equivalent to a Boolean "true". Therefore it is not necessary to compare the result of the Countif with anything. The number returned by Countif will be equivalent to either TRUE or FALSE and will determine which branch of the IF statement is executed.

Comment: MATCH() should be faster than COUNTIF()

Comment: @iDevlop Not with an exact Match() lookup! Read Charles Williams [here](http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeede.htm). Look for "Unsorted data with missing values".

Comment: @teylyn Can you explain what the formula means in detail piece by piece?

Comment: I added an explanation and a variant to the first formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2;$A$2:$A$8;0));A2;TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this formula.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$12,0)),TRUE,"")
```

[image]